# gdalwarp not clipping to index grid

Tags: qgis, clip, gdalwarp

I am using the 4 corners of a grid to clip a raster to it with gdalwarp with the following code: `pkdumpogr -i index.shp -n left1 -n bottom1 -n right1 -n top1| while read Block_ID left1 bottom1 right1 top1; do gdalwarp -overwrite -te $left1 $bottom1 $right1 $top1 TII.tif TII_${Block_ID}.tif;done`

However, gdalwarp is not clipping to the exact boundary as can be seen in the image below. Any ideas of how to fix this?
 [image: grid in red, raster clip in black]

Comment: Could you point to some test image and add a complete and tested gdalwarp command so we could try to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Yep - here is a sample for you to replicate the problem - thanks  [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O80B1PVzIA12921JnrpiGRzhS-MdCZ-4/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: I actually think it is QGIS field calculator not calculating the geometry of the bounding correctly. I was using `xmin($geometry)` but it seems to be slightly inaccurate. Any ideas as to why this is?

Answer (score 1):

I made a test with your data by running command

```
gdalwarp -overwrite -te 653999.7938515543 793999.9204383552 655999.8003834598 795999.9188445071 sampletiff.tif clip.tif
```

Gdalinfo about the result is listing the corner coordinates as

```
Upper Left  (  653999.794,  795999.919) (  7d10'41.28"W, 53d54'38.02"N)
Lower Left  (  653999.794,  793999.920) (  7d10'42.55"W, 53d53'33.32"N)
Upper Right (  655999.800,  795999.919) (  7d 8'51.71"W, 53d54'37.25"N)
Lower Right (  655999.800,  793999.920) (  7d 8'53.02"W, 53d53'32.56"N)
```

Comparison:

```
653999.7938515543 -> 653999.794
793999.9204383552 -> 793999.920
655999.8003834598 -> 655999.800
795999.9188445071 -> 795999.919
```

By these numbers it seems that corners are accurate to the 3rd digit that presents millimeters. Accurace may be even better because gdalinfo truncates the decimals.

From the map I could measure a little larger displacement: 6 millimeters. For some reason it seems that the vectors are a bit misaligned.

That the actual polygon and clipped raster do not align perfectly is probably because the polygons in the vector data are slightly rotated. Here is the top-left polygon as an example

```
POLYGON ((
        653999.7991567788 795999.9203381084, 
        655999.8003834598 795999.9188445071, 
        655999.7949557364 793999.9189999866, 
        653999.7938515543 793999.9204383552, 
        653999.7991567788 795999.9203381084
    ))
```

Comment: If you hover the mouse over the corner and one of those squares and look at the coordinates in QGIS, they are different to what is being represented in the attribute table. Have you noticed that? Do you know of a way of fixing this issue? Thanks

Comment: I could not notice that because I did not use QGIS for testing. I used just gdalwarp for warping and OpenJUMP for capturing the WKT and coordinates.

Comment: No problem - do you know of a way to remove this slight rotation? Or another work around as I cannot leave it like this - thanks for your help

Comment: I opened the data with QGIS and measured a shift of 6 mm. Is that too much for you or is your method leading to larger shift?

Comment: Yes - unfortunately that is too much as in other parts of the overall dataset it is larger than this. It is affected in both x and y directions in other parts of the dataset. Thanks

Comment: Is there a way to align the grid to 90 degree angles perhaps to create a perfect square?

Comment: So, create a new polygon grid that is not rotated or feed just plain coordinates from some function for gdalwarp and you should be fine.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see your comment while I was writing. QGIS may have tools for creating grids or perhaps they call them fishnets. Search the documentation and gis.stackexchange archives.

Comment: Yes, but this grid I created was not rotated by me when I created it. There is a lot of attribute info that I can't afford to loose with this grid. So I was wondering is it possible to rotate this existing grid?

Comment: How did you create it? Do you know what may have happened since that? As you can see the rotation is just few millimeters. Saving the data into PostGIS and using SnapToGrid is one option. You may ask a new question about how to fix your grid.

Comment: I've no idea, but maybe I'll recreate a Disney as a test and see do I still have the same problem. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I recreated the grid and ensured it had no rotation. Once I did this, it clipped perfectly.

Thanks for you help